# Make One Full Power XBox One Adapter from Two Underpowered Adapters

Tags: voltage, watts, amperage

Unfortunately, as of this time, Microsoft does not sell XBox One AC adapters. XBox One adapters are almost always single voltage. I'm an expat who has bought a US XBox One and would like to use it in Europe. Since no one can source an XBox One EU adapter from Microsoft, the only other source are Chinese knockoffs that are underpowered.

Microsoft US Voltage AC Adapter Specifications:
Input: AC 100~127V 4.91A 50/60Hz
Output: DC 12V 17.9A (215W), 5Vsb 1.0A

Chinese Dual Voltage AC Adapter Specifications: 
Input: AC 100~240V 2A, 47~63Hz
Output: DC 12V 10.83A (130W), 5Vsb 1.0A

Can I combine two underpowered adapters, wired up in parallel, to create one full powered source? For both 12V and 5V? What are the risks? Any other options?

There's some hope a knockoff will work as is. AnandTech has tested the draw from an XBox One and found that it only draws 119W max, and as low as 69W otherwise.

http://www.anandtech.com/show/7528/the-xbox-one-mini-review-hardware-analysis/5

Edit - 16-Dec-2013
Thanks for the suggestions about using a stock power supply. Looks like any PC ATX power supply will provide the proper volts at more amps than the knockoffs. They are often dual voltage too. For example:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817152019

This ATX power supply has +12V@18A on pins 10 and 11 (yellow wires) and +5VSB@2.0A on pins 9 (purple wire).

How do I hook up the ATX power supply to the XBox One's two prong connector?

http://www.tinydeal.com/eu-plug-ac-adapter-power-supply-for-xbox-one-p-106421.html

(1) Should I bundle multiple ATX +12V wires together or can I use just a single wire?

(2) I assume that ATX +5VSB amps, being double the XBox One adapter, is ok to use?

(3) I'm making an assumption that the XBox's dual prong plug needs +5V and ground on one prong, and +12V and ground on the other.

(4) I can probably wire the XBox One plug to an ATX female to mate with the ATX power supply.

(5) What are the caveats and am I missing anything?

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to use the official Microsoft adapter with a high-quality 120-220V adapter

Comment: Combining adapters in parallel should and MAY work. Safer, as Earlz says, is to use a 230/120 transformer to power a 110V adapter. Most modern "PC" power supplies could be rigged to provide the required voltages and power levels.

Comment: Added further info and questions about using an ATX power supply.

Comment: Received the XBox One knockoff. Ugh. It works, has an extremely loud fan, inspires no confidence, hasn't set fire to my house and hasn't electrocuted me. It's a stopgap measure for a month until I catch up with a real power source.

Comment: Why not just use a voltage converter? They're generally fairly cheap.

Comment: Ultimately a voltage converter may be the answer. They are 4x more expensive than the knockoff, big, bulky, and have their own set of problems. The ideal is to buy an adapter from Microsoft but they still haven't released a SKU.

Comment: I am confused... Don't ATX power supplies get converted to Benchtop power supplies all the time? We cut all the molex ends and use each colored lead for its respective voltage... In most cases 12V is Yellow. Red is 5V and Orange is 3.3... Ground is Black. So can't we just find a say 500W ATX Power Supply Capable then of 25A on 12V Line... and route 12v to the Xbox one with some grounds ... Boom - Reliable Clean xbox one Power brick? Hmph
Just my 2cents... Guess I'll try it and post a YouTube Vid.

Comment: I'm the OP. Just following up. Turns out I didn't bond with my XBox One, brought it back to the USA, gave it too a happy adolescent. I used the knockoff adapter for one week and decided the XBox One isn't for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I THINK : you've got to follow the guide to connect the ATX power supply of the ATX to x360 SLIM converter.

Which can be found here : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=brIcxSPUF7Q

title : "Repairing XBOX 360 - Part #2 - Powering from PC ATX power supply and taking apart the XBOX!"

And when I saw that, and read about the 5v and 12v, I Couldn't but notice how similar the X360 Slim connector is to the XBOX ONE. It seems identical! except it's 135Watt and the XBOX ONE is max 215Watt but like anandtech says it doesn't use all the juice.

But this also opens another simple fact: If the slim connector is the same as the XBOX ONE, then you can also use an old European X360 fat power supply and put a "Fat to slim converter" on it and it should work.

http://www.avforums.com/threads/converting-360-fat-power-supply-to-360-slim-safe.1452242/

You can buy these converters cheaply on ebay.

The old x360 fat supply is 203Watt which would be more adequate then the Chinese clones of 135Watt which I find to similar to the 135watt X360 slim Chinese clones.

Answer (score 4):

Putting two voltage sources in parallel is usually a Bad Idea<sup>tm</sup>, unless they are expressly designed for such. If these supplies are regulated (and they may or may not be), then each might be *slightly* different voltages, even though they both say "12V". They can't be *exactly* the same, due to manufacturing variation.

Consequently, if you put two in parallel, one *may* end up providing all the current and overheat. Without knowing specifically what power supplies you have, we can't know for sure if they will start a fire, self-destruct, simply fail to work, damage your XBox, or work fine.

But why bother? It is not difficult to find a 12V, 17.9A or 5, 1.0A power supply, if you look outside the "XBox" microcosm. Why not just buy the right power supply and put the right connector on it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd just run the Chinese adapter as is, unless I saw reports that they always burned out quickly. Even if it eventually fails, your XBox won't be damaged, just the adapter; get another, they're only a few bucks.

If you really wanted to build something, instead of running two XBox adapters in parallel, look for a single power adapter that has the correct rating (maybe something for a laptop), clip the end, and replace it with the plug for the XBox (I'm assuming the XBox has some proprietary plug, but if it's a standard DC plug you won't even have to do that).

Comment: "Even if it eventually fails, your XBox won't be damaged" what? There have been reports of people DYING because of cheap adapters that bridged the 220V input with the 5V output. If the 5V or 12V input can withstand that, then I would be incredibly impressed

Comment: Can you share these reports with us? A 119W device in a 130W supply will subject it to stress, but there isn't any evidence that this particular adapter is so poorly designed as to fail with deadly results like you say.

Comment: @M there isn't, but with most cheap chinese knock offs, there is no real liability of the company either. see http://www.zdnet.com/cn/faulty-charger-not-iphone-could-have-killed-chinese-stewardess-7000018135/

Comment: This is the kind of design you sometimes get in [cheap "chinese" knockoffs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=keaE7QTKTYE).